# How to Use Keepass Auto-type with Ubuntu One

Tags: keepass

I use Keepass 2 on various platforms, and would like to use auto-type to log in to Ubuntu One. However, the Ubuntu One [login page](https://login.launchpad.net/+login) has a title of only "Log In", which is a) used on many other pages, and b) not a very good name for the Keepass entry anyway.

Of course, I can bring up the Keepass window, find the Launchpad/Ubuntu One entry, select it, and then type Ctrl-V to do the auto-login, but it would be nice if the standard auto-login key (i.e., Ctrl-Alt-A on Windows) would just be able to find the entry itself.

Is there some trick I can use to make the standard auto-login work? Failing that, to whom can I report this as a problem with the Launchpad login page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Keepass, but a bit of research after thinking about your question leads me to suggest that you use [The URL in Title Bar plugin](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#urlintitle) which supports Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.

Enable the option 'An entry matches if its URL is contained in the target window title' in KeePass 2.x (<kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>Advanced</kbd>, auto-type by URL can be realized. *Some* scripts just append the host/domain; in this case the option 'An entry matches if the host component of its URL is contained in the target window title' should be enabled.

Sources:

http://keepass.info/features.html#lnkdragdrop

http://keepass.info/help/v2/plugins.html

http://keepass.info/plugins.html

Comment: I'm glad you posted a link to a list of various plugin options; it turns out that Host in Title plugin is the best option for me. Thanks.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I'm glad it wasa useful. I'm always [eager to help.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help/16265#16265)